# Web Maps - Responsibilities of frontend & backend

Tags: leaflet, gis, openlayers

When using web map services such as Leaflet/Openlayers etc, are different raster layers fetched separately and laid on top of each other client-side, or are they composed on the server side?

Thank you

Comment: Depends. Some use cases call for raster processes on the server side, some use cases call for offloading work to the client.

Comment: You may also want to try asking this on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you make a separate request for each layer then the server will generate one image for each layer. However, if you make a request with several layers in it then the server will send back one combined image for all the layers, this is usually fastest.